# Cursor in Hive?

Tags: sql, ruby, hive

As the title says, does Hive support cursors, or something like them? I have a large query that I'd like to fetch in chunks, but I can't seem to find a Hive friendly solution.

Thanks,
Kyle

Comment: How are you pulling your data? (For example -- is this in Java? Are you using a "command-line" driver, or the JDBC driver, or . . . ?)

Comment: Pulling it into ruby. I'm searching for a solution that doesn't involve sticking it in a variable and tokenizing in ruby.

Comment: So are you using a Thrift client, such as is described at http://blog.fingertap.org/post/1255463384/hive-thrift-client?

Comment: (Let me put this a different way: in Java, the answer is "yes: you can set the prefetch size, so that whole chunks are retrieved at a time". But for me to make that answer useful to you, I need to know what you're doing. How are you pulling the data?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such thing in Hive. You can not really have pagination using Hive. Only thing you can do is to execute your hive query and get the ResultSet, then iterate through it.

The interesting part is how you want to handle the large results. You don't normally want to load all the results in memory, instead, you can stream back your query results. For example, if you are write the results into csv, instead of having a big object containing all the query results before you start writing to csv which potentially can use up your memory, you can handle them iteratively on the wire and write in chunk to your csv file.